# How to get vim config variable value in ruby vim plugin?

Tags: ruby, vim, vim-plugin

There is a vim plugin, which allows customization using a variable in vimrc:

```
let g:foo_plugin_command="bar"
```

How can i get the value of this variable in a ruby method that is part of the plugin code?

Answer (score 1):

Vim::evaluate can be used to get vim global variable values and pass it to Ruby

```
Model.new.run('abc', 123, Vim.evaluate('g:foo_plugin_command'))
```